# Read search string from a file and add a string for a field in another file

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk, sed

i have a req to read 2 files say file1 and file2

file1 has search strings

file2 has some data

Requirement is to read search string line by line from file 1 and search that string against lines in file 2 and if found add "_done" for 2 field in file2.

Example:
file1: has

```
BEN2T
KEN3T
MILDRED
```

file2: has

```
RICKy2 Monthly    "CASE, WORKLOAD, INVENTORY" Workload-cli
BEN2T Monthly   INTERFACES      Interface-cli
KEN3T Daily   INTERFACES      Interface-cli
MARCUS3 Monthly   "CASE, WORKLOAD, EMPLOYMENT SERVICES, INVENTORY"    Workload-cli
NANCY2 Monthly   "CASE, WORKLOAD, EMPLOYMENT SERVICES, INVENTORY"    Workload-cli
MILDRED Monthly "FISCAL, CLAIMS"    Port
```

Now expected output.txt will be like below:

```
RICKy2 Monthly    "CASE, WORKLOAD, INVENTORY" Workload-cli
BEN2T Monthly_done   INTERFACES      Interface-cli
KEN3T Daily_done   INTERFACES      Interface-cli
MARCUS3 Monthly   "CASE, WORKLOAD, EMPLOYMENT SERVICES, INVENTORY"    Workload-cli
NANCY2 Monthly   "CASE, WORKLOAD, EMPLOYMENT SERVICES, INVENTORY"    Workload-cli
MILDRED Monthly_done    "FISCAL, CLAIMS"    Port
```

tried:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput

with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(text_to_search, replacement_text), end='')
```

but this is replacing the file.

Im okay with shell or python

Thankyou

Comment: By seeing your profile came to know that sometime you don't select any of the answers as correct answers out of all. Request you to please give it sometime and when you see few answers then try to select any one of them as correct one, you could do this for your previous questions too, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 sure -- i always give vote to the answers i didnt even notice there is a Tick mark for selecting the answer until now.

Comment: Np, we all learn new things always,cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[tolower($0)];next} {$2=tolower($1) in a?$2"_done":$2} 1' Input_file1   Input_file2
```

Or as per @blhsing's comment following may also help here.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program here.
FNR==NR{                                ##checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when fir Input_file isbeing read.
  a[tolower($0)]                        ##Creating an array named a whose index is value of current line andtolower changes line to all lower characters.
  next                                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
tolower($1) in a{                       ##checking if lower value of $1 is present in array a if yes then do following.
  $2=$2"_done"                          ##Appending _done to value of $2 here.
}
1
'   file1  file2                        ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for code now.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program here.
FNR==NR{                                ##checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when fir Input_file isbeing read.
  a[tolower($0)]                        ##Creating an array named a whose index is value of current line andtolower changes line to all lower characters.
  next                                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{                                       ##Starting a block here which will be executed once 2nd Input_file named Input_file2 is being read.
  $2=tolower($1) in a?$2"_done":$2      ##Here checking condition if lower value of $1 is present in array a if yes then append _done to$2 or keep it as it is.
}                                       ##Closing block here.
1                                       ##Mentioning 1 here will print edited/non-edited value of line.
'   Input_file1   Input_file2           ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
RICKy2 Monthly "CASE, WORKLOAD, INVENTORY" Workload-cli
BEN2T Monthly_done INTERFACES Interface-cli
KEN3T Daily_done INTERFACES Interface-cli
MARCUS3 Monthly "CASE, WORKLOAD, EMPLOYMENT SERVICES, INVENTORY" Workload-cli
NANCY2 Monthly "CASE, WORKLOAD, EMPLOYMENT SERVICES, INVENTORY" Workload-cli
MILDRED Monthly_done "FISCAL, CLAIMS" Port
```

Comment: Thankyou @RavinderSingh13

Comment: Good `awk` solution. I would do `tolower($1) in a{$2=$2"_done"}` instead of `{$2=tolower($1) in a?$2"_done":$2}` for better clarity.

Comment: @blhsing, thank you for encouragement, sure added your suggestion `awk` too in there, cheers.

Comment: Why are you calling `tolower()`? There's no indication I can see that a case insensitive match would be necessary or even desirable. Also, rather than writing `$2` twice in the ternary in `$2=tolower($1) in a?$2"_done":$2` you could make it `$2=$2(tolower($1) in a? "_done":"")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use read `file1` into a set so that you can use a generator expression to look for matches with names generated from the `csv.reader` method:

```
import csv
done = set(map(str.rstrip, open('file1')))
with open('file2_new', 'w') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows((name, freq + 'done', *rest) for name, freq, *rest in csv.reader(open('file2'), delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True) if name in done)
```